# GNU C comiler version 10.3.0, was not found. Vmware

Tags: linux, vmware, kali-linux

[pic][1]
I get this error after installing VMware. From other questions in this forum, I tried to install build-essential, then update and upgrade, but it didn't solve my problem. Also, I tried installing GCC 10.3.0 version from previous releases but I couldn't wrap up my head around how I could direct location to the folder, because it expects a file. I'm using Kali Linux 2021.4
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMfqM.png

Comment: If you open a terminal and type `which gcc` and `gcc --version` what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try running
- sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic.

then open your vmware & in 1st window and click Install, wait for about 7 mins & vmware will be open.